# How to check radiobutton with Enum value in Asp.net core mvc view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, radio-button

I have rendered my view like below

```
<div class="row row-margin-zero">
    <label class="radio-inline margin-rightt-ten margin-leftt-five margin-top-none">
        <input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.Countries" name="optradio"  value="1" class="margin-rightt-five">
        America
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline margin-rightt-ten margin-leftt-five margin-top-none">
        <input type="radio"  asp-for="@Model.Countries" name="optradio" value="2" class="margin-rightt-five">
        Australia
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline margin-rightt-ten margin-leftt-five margin-top-none">
        <input type="radio"  asp-for="@Model.Countries" name="optradio" value="0" class="margin-rightt-five">
        Eng
    </label>
</div>
```

Below is my Enum

```
public Enum Countries {America,Eng,Australia}.
```

How can i checked the radiobuttons with enum value specified in Model?

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you have an enum of `Countries` and also a ViewModel that has a property of `Country`:

```cs
public enum Countries {America, Eng, Australia};

public class XModel{
    // ... other props

    public Countries Country{get;set;}
}
```

To render radiobuttons for Country, you can get all the possible values by `System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries))` such that you can render them all with a simple loop.

```
@model XModel

@foreach( var c in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries)) )
{
    <label asp-for="Country">@c</label>
    <input type="radio" asp-for="Country" value="@((int)c)" />
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

---

**[Edit]**:

> how can i show the selected value

Simply add a `checked` attribute dynamically:

```
@foreach( var c in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries)).OfType<Countries>() )
{
    <label asp-for="Country">@c</label>
    <input type="radio" asp-for="Country" value="@((int)c)"  checked="@(c == Model?.Country)" />
}
```

Comment: yes.. i asked how can i show the selected value. let's say xmodel contains America as selected.

Comment: @tiger Oh, I see. To do that,  simply add an attribute of `checked={true_or_false}`. Please check my updated answer for more details :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `<input type='radio'>` has some bugs. I recommend using `@Html.RadioButtonFor` instead.

e.g.

```cs
@foreach (var c in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries)))
{
    <label class="radio-inline margin-rightt-ten margin-leftt-five margin-top-none">
        @(Html.RadioButtonFor<Countries>(m => m.Countries,(Countries)c, null))
        @c
    </label>
}
```